# JUnit5 testing flattened ArrayList results in false

Tags: java, list, junit5

Why does Junit test show me, that AssertEquals is false for my test?

I am flattening this structure and running Junit5 test against it.

```
Arrays.asList("a", 
    Arrays.asList("b",
        Arrays.asList("c", "d")), "e")
```

Junit test:

```
@Test
public void shouldFlattenAListOfList() throws Exception {
    List<String> flatten = Problem07.flatten(Arrays.asList("a", Arrays.asList("b",
            Arrays.asList("c", "d")), "e"), String.class);
    assertEquals(flatten.size(), 5);
    System.out.println(flatten == Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")); // prints: false
    assertEquals(flatten, Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"));
}
```

**Results in error, AssertionFailedError. I see that difference is in whitespaces, and cannot solve this issue.**

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :[a,  b,  c,  d,  e]
Actual   :[a, b, c, d, e]
```

Plain class with static method:

```
public class Problem07 {
    static List<String> flatten(Collection<?> objects, Object aClass) {
        if (objects == null) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }

        if (objects.isEmpty()) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }

        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();

        /*TODO generify for other classes, not only hardcoded String*/
        objects.forEach(o -> {
            if (o instanceof ArrayList) {
                ArrayList<String> o1 = (ArrayList<String>) o;
                strings.addAll(o1);
            } else {
                strings.add(o.toString());
            }
        });

        String formattedString = strings.toString()
                .replace("[", "")  //remove the right bracket
                .replace("]", "");  //remove the left bracket

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(formattedString.split(",")));

        System.out.println(list);//prints: [a,  b,  c,  d,  e]

        return list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `formattedString` obtained by calling `List.toString()` will introduce additional space between the elements due to default `toString()` formatting. This mean that instead of "a", "b", "c", ... your flattened list is going to contain contain "a", " b", " c", ... and obviously String "b" is not equal to String " b".

You shouldn't rely on `toString()` and `split()` to obtain the flattened list. You can hack it to remove the superficial spaces but it would be better to use recursion to iterate through each level of nesting in `objects` collection.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the way you are flattening the Array is not to recommend to do that job. You are using `strings.toString()` to get a String and then removing brackets from it. I will suggest using `recursion` for `flattening` the list. Here I have modified your code using recursion.

```
static List<String> flatten(Collection<?> objects, Object aClass) {
        if (objects == null) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        if (objects.isEmpty()) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        objects.forEach(o -> {
            if (o instanceof List) {
                strings.addAll(flatten((List)o,String.class));
            } else {
                strings.add(o.toString());
            }
        });
        return strings;
    }
```

One more suggestion please don't use `==` to check logical equality use `equals` instead.